# Getting "Unable to switch encoding" error in SQLServer

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have 2 database instances of SQL Server.

When I am trying to save XML into a table for one of the databases, it is working fine but for other instance I'm getting an error:

> Unable to switch encoding                                                              getting following error "Caused by: org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.ReportingSQLException: XML parsing: line 1, character 39, unable to switch the encoding {prepstmnt 1671783333 UPDATE MYTable SET CreateDate = ?, ExpiryDate = ?, XMLData = ? WHERE ID = ? [params=(Timestamp) 2013-07-10 18:52:12.552, (Timestamp) 2013-07-11 06:52:12.552, (String)

Comment: @user2567303 Are you really running Microsoft SQL Server on Linux? I was under the impression that that particular DBMS only runs on Windows OS.

Comment: Yes Microsoft SQL Server 2008 on Linux.

Comment: @huMptyduMpty : i have read that article also , but actual problem is DB instance on Windows accepting UTF-8 and that on Linux acccepting UTF-16.

Comment: @user2567303 How is that possible?

Comment: @jpw : Right now lets forget about Windows OR Linux, if i am having 2 database instances of SQL Server.They are having same schemas. Then Why i am getting error?